# Logical test to determine if a value exists in a grouped dataframe in R (tidy solution)

Tags: r, logical-operators

I would like to test if a value exists between two values in a large dataframe that I've grouped by a factor. Basically, I have a column with numerical values and I'd like to test if any rows have a value between -5 and 5. Here's an example:

```
x <- tibble(value = c(-10, 8, 10, 0, 6, 10), group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    logical_test = if_else(any(value >= -5) & any(value <= 5), TRUE, FALSE)
  )
```

Group `A` should be `FALSE`. It does not have a value between -5 and 5; however, the test shows `TRUE`. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. Is `any()` not the correct function here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `any(value >= -5 & value <= 5)` or  `any(between(value, -5, 5))` - `if_else()` is redundant here.

Comment: To understand the difference, your code `any(value >= -5) & any(value <= 5)` is asking "is any value >= -5? And, is any value <= 5", but they could be different values. `any(value >= -5 & value <= 5)` fixes that issue, looking for any value that is both >= -5 and <= 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you only need to use `any` once and do not need `ifelse` as using `any` will already return a logical.

```
library(dplyr)

x <-
  tibble(value = c(-10, 8, 10, 0, 6, 10),
         group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')) 

x %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(logical_test = any(value >= -5 & value <= 5))
```

**Output**

```
  value group logical_test
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>       
1   -10 A     FALSE       
2     8 A     FALSE       
3    10 A     FALSE       
4     0 B     TRUE        
5     6 B     TRUE        
6    10 B     TRUE
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)[, test := any(value >= -5 & value <= 5), by = group]
```

Or with base R:

```
x$logical_test <- as.logical(ave(x$value, x$group, FUN = \(x) any(x >= -5 & x <= 5)))
```